# jQuery: Add class depending on URL in the best way

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML for a progress meter:

```
<div class="col-md-3" style="margin-left: -20px;">
    <div class="progress-pos active" id="progess-1">
    <div class="progress-pos-inner">
        Login
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 progress-pos-container">
    <div class="progress-pos" id="progess-2">
    <div class="progress-pos-inner">
        Scan Items
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 progress-pos-container">
    <div class="progress-pos" id="progess-3">
    <div class="progress-pos-inner">
        Confirm Address
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 progress-pos-container">
    <div class="progress-pos" id="progess-4">
    <div class="progress-pos-inner">
        Finished
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I use the following jQuery to add/remove classes depending on the URL.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if(location.search == "?route=account/login&SSL"){
    $("#progess-1").addClass("active");
    }
    if(location.search == "?route=checkout/cart"){
    $("#progess-2").addClass("active");
    $("#progess-1").addClass("inactive");
    }
    if(location.search == "?route=checkout/checkout"){
    $("#progess-3").addClass("active");
    $("#progess-1").addClass("inactive");
    $("#progess-2").addClass("inactive");
    }
    if(location.search == "?route=checkout/success"){
    $("#progess-4").addClass("active");
    $("#progess-1").addClass("inactive");
    $("#progess-2").addClass("inactive");
    $("#progess-3").addClass("inactive");
    }
});
```

I know that this isn't the best way to acomplish this (Even though the code does work), as I have to repeat the same thing over and over. I have tried `prev()` but it didn't seem to work.

What is the best way to go about it?

**EDIT:** To be clear, not all elements apart from the one with the `active` class should be given the class of `active`, just the ones prior.

**EDIT 2:**

Current Activity:

User is on page `?route=account/login&SSL`, `#progress-1` is give the class of `.active`.

User progresses to `?route=checkout/cart` sucessfully, and `#progress-1` is given the class of `.inactive` and `#progress-2` is `.active`

User progresses to `?route=checkout/checkout` sucessfully, and `#progress-1` & `#progress-2` are given the class of `.inactive` and `#progress-3` is `.active` and so on.

Comment: I think, you can do something similar to: $('.all-links').addClass('inactive'); $('.' + location.search).addClass('active'). Let me know if it makes sense

Comment: @Vnuuk Thanks for the help, but it doesn't make make much sense to me as I remain a noob at js. :)

Comment: Let me explain. #1. You need to modify HTML and #progess-N ids put what you may have in URL. Is is clear?

Comment: mplungjan, not sure I follow you..

Comment: I'd be keeping the HTML from changing, that seems to be pretty concise

Comment: A. Change the `if`s to [`switch`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp). B. Change the script to a structure like this: `('.progress-pos').removeClass('inactive active').not('active_selector').addClass('inactive'); $('active_selector').addClass('active');`

Comment: @mplungjan I do not add inactive to all. I add inactive to the `#progress-*` element prior to the active element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    // Re-set all on entry
    $("#progess-1, #progess-2, #progess-3, #progress-4").removeClass("inactive active");

    // Then check for the correct one to make active
    if(location.search == "?route=account/login&SSL")
        $("#progess-1").addClass("active");
    else if(location.search == "?route=checkout/cart")
    {
        $("#progess-2").addClass("active");
        $("#progess-1").addClass("inactive");
    }
    else if(location.search == "?route=checkout/checkout")
    {
        $("#progess-3").addClass("active");
        $("#progess-1,#progess-2").addClass("inactive");
    }
    else if(location.search == "?route=checkout/success")
    {
        $("#progess-4").addClass("active");
        $("#progess-1,#progess-2,#progess-3").addClass("inactive");
    }
});
```

This can also be achieved by replacing the if statement with a switch.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I believe that this won't have the intended affect - only the elements prior to the active one should be inactive,not the ones after, as the user has not yet completed that section.

Comment: Within your solution you said it worked as you intended, you manually set the previous ones to inactive manually within each statement.

Comment: Apologies, wrote too fast. Edited.

Comment: @harley_woop, i'll quickly edit the solution to meet your needs

Comment: @harley_woop each step in the progress will now be active. If you're on step 2, step one and two will be highlighted whilst step 3 and 4 will remain inactive.

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer, however I wasn't being clear. If the user was on `?route=checkout/cart`, then `#progress-2` should be active, `#progress-1` should be inactive, and `#progress-3` & `#progress-4` would be unaffected, and so on. Only the elements previous to the currently `.active` element should be `.inactive`. I should rewrite the question with current, correct behaviour.

Comment: @harley_woop Surely they're either active or they're not.

Comment: That would have been helpful yes.

Comment: @harley_woop seems weird that further steps don't have the inactive class, but the solution should work as you want,

Comment: @JordanLowe Yeah, I should name it "completed", better semantics I suppose.